# data.plot.bar() Mixing up index labels

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, jupyter, kaggle

I have the below code to provide me a graph in a jupyter notebook, however it seems to be mislabeling the categories.  When I make a change in the data to a cell in the node outage column that should be classified as a low traffic cell, it is changing the bar labeled mid traffic. looking at the data it seems to me assiging the correct user_category based on my cut points, so I can not see why it is affecting the mid traffic bar when I change a 0 to a 1 in the node outage column. Anyone have any ideas? PS this is my 1st question on the forums here so let me know if im not providing what is needed to assist. Thanks! (Data thats X'd out is due to being proprietary but should be irrelevant to the question here)

```
train.head(10)

site    past_alarms          weather_event  max_users   node_outage
xxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     Thunderstorm   341         N
xxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     Tornado        71          Y
xxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     None           294         N
xxxxxx  None                 None           395         N
xxxxxx  None                 None           422         N
xxxxxx  None                 None           331         N
xxxxxx  None                 Tornado        260         N
xxxxxx  None                 None           79          N
xxxxxx  None                 None           240         N
xxxxxx  None                 None           370         N

def process_users(df,cut_points,label_names):
    df["user_categories"] = pd.cut(df["max_users"],cut_points,labels=label_names)
    return df

cut_points = [1, 100, 350, 550]
label_names  = ["Low_Traffic","Mid_Traffic","High_Traffic"]

train = process_users(train,cut_points,label_names)

users_cat_pivot = 
train.pivot_table(index="user_categories",values="node_outage")
users_cat_pivot.plot.bar()
plt.show()

<graph shown here>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify what is happening here if it happens to help anyone else in the future.  What it happening is its creating the index based on the 1st thing it sees, so if you notice that the 1st row in the data above would be classified as Mid traffic based on the cut points I have, it is naming the 1st column in the graph mid.  If i reorder the data before importing to train so that low is 1st, it orders the index correctly.  I am sure there is also a way to code that in the line, if anyone happens to know that feel free to respond, but at least I know why its happening.